# Composer on docker: Uncaught Error: Class not found

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, packagist

I'm trying to build a minimal docker image to use [packagist.org/packages/nikic/php-parser](https://packagist.org/packages/nikic/php-parser%5C):

```dockerfile
FROM php
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install zip -y
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
COPY . .
```

Installing the (single) dependency goes smooth (done *outside* `Dockerfile` for exposition):

```
root@e1aa9cdb4e13:/# composer install
< ... omitted for brevity ... >
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading nikic/php-parser (v5.0.2)
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v5.0.2): Extracting archive
Generating autoload files
```

When I try to run the example in the docs, I crash:

```
root@e1aa9cdb4e13:/# php main.php
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpParser\ParserFactory" not found in /main.php:15
```

Here is the example I use (taken *"as-is"* from [the docs](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#quick-start)):

```php
<?php
use PhpParser\Error;
use PhpParser\NodeDumper;
use PhpParser\ParserFactory;

$code = <<<'CODE'
<?php

function test($foo)
{
    var_dump($foo);
}
CODE;

$parser = (new ParserFactory())->createForNewestSupportedVersion();
try {
    $ast = $parser->parse($code);
} catch (Error $error) {
    echo "Parse error: {$error->getMessage()}\n";
    return;
}

$dumper = new NodeDumper;
echo $dumper->dump($ast) . "\n";
```

**EDIT**

Adding an explicit `include` from `vendor` directory,
I seem to get one (tiny ?) step farther:

```php
include "/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/ParserFactory.php";
```

new error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpParser\PhpVersion" not found in /vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/ParserFactory.php:32
```

Comment: Is this really related to Docker, Composer or Packagist? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Wheer are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase it turns out I was missing a `require '/vendor/autoload.php'`. I posted this fact as an answer in case someone else hits a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was missing a single statement:

```php
<?php
require '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

When I added this line it worked perfectly:

```
root@e1aa9cdb4e13:/# php main.php
array(
    0: Stmt_Function(
        attrGroups: array(
        )
        byRef: false
        name: Identifier(
            name: test
        )
< ... omitted for brevity ... >
```

---

<sup>*</sup> I found the reference [here](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/master/doc/2_Usage_of_basic_components.markdown#bootstrapping)